# Commands not executed with %comspec% /k

Tags: windows, batch, environment-variables

I am trying to execute a `.bat` file with a set of commands which can be executed individually through the command line, but not all together through the script:

```
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
cd C:\pathname
msbuild filename.vcproj
cd Debug
filename.exe
```

Basically I am trying to call the Visual Studio command line, then build a project through it, and after that run the generated `.exe`.

The script stops at the first line when the command line environment variable is set to be directed towards the Visual Studio; something like this:

```
C:\Users\myusername\Desktop> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x86 tools.
C:\Users\myusername\Desktop>
```

The rest of the commands are not called and the script ends at this point.

The /k option tells to run the command and  return to the command line, is this the problem? Any suggestion how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is the variable comspec defined? Because with command %comspec%... you try to execute the content of variable as program name

Comment: Try adding 'exit' to the end of vcvarsall.bat.

Comment: What output do you get? Where does it stop working?

Comment: C:\Users\kiuser\Desktop>C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files\Micros
oft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x86 tools.

C:\Users\kiuser\Desktop>

Comment: this is the output I get only that the enviroment is set for using MS VS 2008

Comment: (0) When people ask you to clarify your question, [edit] your question; do not reply in comments (***especially*** when your reply is multiple lines, as you did, above).  (1) What, exactly, happens when you just type `""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86` at the command prompt?  What about `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86` (without the extra quote characters)?  (2) Why do you have those extra quote characters, anyway?  (3) What happens if you type `exit` after the error you have described?  (4) Try changing `/k` to `/c`.

Answer (score 1):

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
cd C:\pathname
msbuild filename.vcproj
cd Debug
filename.exe
```

### Explanation:

> `VCVarsall.bat` is Visual Studio Command Prompt tool in Visual Studio.
>   It's the tool that allows you to set various options for the
>   integrated development environment (IDE) as well as *build, debug, and
>   deploy projects* **from the command line**.

Read the `VCVarsall.bat`, you can see the way of "*set various options*": it calls further scripts to check presence (and validity if necessary) of some *folders* (e.g. `HTML Help Workshop`), some *registry entries*, some  *environment variables* (e.g. `%VS90COMNTOOLS%`) and so on. If necessary, it (re)defines some environment variables (e.g. `%LIBPATH%` and even `%PATH%`) using `set`  command.

According to [Command-Line Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771320.aspx), `%comspec%` command starts a new instance of the command interpreter  (`cmd.exe`). Unfortunately, any changes to environment variables made there will not affect other CMD sessions that are already running on the machine!

Hence, use `call "...\vcvarsall.bat" x86` (note `"` double quotes are *not doubled*.) Read: `call` [calls one batch program from another without stopping the parent batch program](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732835.aspx).

Comment: what I did was to edit vcvarsall.bat and put the call of myscript.bat in the x86 option that triggered both the Visual Studio command line and myscript.bat when I run the vcvarsall.bat therefore my issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

Ifyou want control from a called batch file to return to the calling batch use the call command. `call /?`.